# How can I import a function from source in r and keep hebrew characters

Tags: r, encoding, hebrew

I'm having problems with language encoding in R when loading a function from a file using `source()`.

The function (defined below) takes a text file in hebrew and searches for specific words. If I have the function defined as part of an RStudio script, everything works as expected. But if I save the function to disk, load it using `source`, the hebrew search string is converted into what appears to be gibberish and the search fails to find the search string. The search string is definitely present in the text file, and that is correctly loaded in hebrew.

I've tried surrounding the hebrew with `utf8::as_utf8("מסכת")`, for example, but that has no effect.

Here's the function code & libraries:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

test_fn <- function(x) {
    raw_text <- read_html(x)
    masechet <- raw_text %>% html_nodes("h2") %>%
        head(1) %>% html_text() %>%
        str_remove("מסכת") %>%
        str_remove("פרק א") %>% str_trim
    message(masechet)
}
```

To be clear: if that's part of an RStudio window, it all works fine. But if I load it like this:

```
assemble <- source("test.r")
test_fn <- assemble$value
```

I get the following for the hebrew text:

```
     str_remove("×¤×¨×§ ×") %>% str_trim
```

And if I try to tell `source()` to use encoding I get an error and it doesn't load at all:

```
assemble <- source("test_fn.r", encoding = "UTF-8")
Error in source("test_fn.r", encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  test_fn.r:5:20: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING
4:         head(1) %>% html_text() %>%
5:         str_remove("
                      ^
In addition: Warning message:
In readLines(file, warn = FALSE) :
  invalid input found on input connection 'test_fn.r'
```

Running on Windows 10 in UK.
Sys.getlocale() returns the following:
`"LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"`
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the R file itself? You are on windows which normally saves files using Latin-1, not UTF-8 encoding. Make sure your actual script file uses UTF-8 encoding. That's something you need to set when you write the file. It's not something you can change just when you read the file.

Comment: I saved the file to disk from Notepad++ and explicitly set the encoding to UTF-8. Only after that did I throw my hands up and turn here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MrFlick noted, you are on Windows; R on Windows has known problems with UTF-8 strings, because Windows doesn't support them the way Unix-alikes do.

What I'd suggest you do is to make sure your code files are pure ASCII.  To do this, you'll need to encode your Hebrew strings using `\uXXXX` escapes.  It's a little painful to find those, but this function will do it for you:

```
asEscapes <- function(x) 
  cat(paste0('"', paste(sprintf("\\u%x", utf8ToInt(x)), collapse = ""), '"'))
```

For example,

```
asEscapes("מסכת")
# "\u5de\u5e1\u5db\u5ea"
```

So you'd use `str_remove("\u5de\u5e1\u5db\u5ea")` in place of `str_remove("מסכת")` and you should get the same results.

Comment: Another day, another new function to explore. Removes any issues relating to encoding, so this is a big help.